# Call Converter for each item in DatGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have DataGrid with Binding to ObservableCollection. I need to convert each Item from entity provided by ObservableCollection to my custom type "On the fly". To Achieve such behaviour I have added following XAML markup:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CustomGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionView}" >
                <DataGrid.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CustomConverter}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.ItemTemplate>
            </DataGrid>
```

In above sample CollectionView is ObservableCollection and CustomConverter is my own developed Converter
With above code I want to convert each entity provided by CollectionView to another type with CustomConverter.

But, unfortunally, the code does not work. I  have set brekpoint inside CustomConverter and it never invokes.
Does it exists some way to convert the values?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the [DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplateselector.aspx)
or [DataGrid.ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx)

Another option is to create your custom style for each item. Assuming that each row has the same set of columns.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CustomGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionView}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
        <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
            <l:DataGridItemItemStyleSelector />
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
</DataGrid>
```

with the style defined as:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataGridItemItemStyleSelector : StyleSelector
    {
        public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            Employee targetIem = item as Employee;
            if (targetIem != null)
            {
                if (targetIem.Id == 0)
                {
                    return (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("ResourceNameDefined");
                }
                else
                {
                    return base.SelectStyle(item, container);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return base.SelectStyle(item, container);
            }

        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!